# Lua code golf problem

Tags: lua

I've been playing around with this code golf problem: 
https://www.spoj.pl/SHORTEN/problems/KAMIL/

I've got my solution down to 55 characters:

```
for l in io.lines()do print(2^#l:gsub("[^TDLF]",""))end
```

Now, the shortest submitted solution in Lua is 47 characters long. I just 
can't figure out how to further reduce mine and it's been driving me crazy. 
Does anyone have a hint for me? I've tried working on io.read("*a") to get 
rid of the loop but it didn't help.

Comment: I think, to solve spoj is like to solve PE. SO is not a good place for it. It's wrong.

Comment: This is not what the code-golf tag is for: see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-golf/info

Answer (score 0):

### Lua (54 chars)

```
repeat print(2^#io.read():gsub('[^TDLF]',''))until nil
```

errors on completion, so maybe not ok

otherwise I spent a while experimenting with the second return of gsub; but you always seem to gain one character with the return selecting.

Answer (score -3):

### Perl 5 (28 characters)

Terrible start, I should be doing a lot better for Perl. But I'm rusty. If I could initialize

```
print 2**s/[TLDF]//g,$/for<>
```

I know you wanted Lua, but I'm noticing the site allows for all languages except Perl 6. So I wanted to submit an entry :-)